# Warn : GDB connection 1 on target STM32F103C8Tx.cpu not halted undefined debug reason 8 - target needs reset in Linux Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: arm, stm32, openocd, stm32cubeide, stm32f1

I'm using STM32CubeIDE on Kubuntu Linux and when I want to program my microcontroller it gives me this error

**Image**
[Error while trying to upload the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S691p.jpg)

**CubeIDE console error**

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-00443-gcf12591 (2022-02-09-13:30) [ST Internal]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : STLINK V2J37S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.152911
Info : Unable to match requested speed 8000 kHz, using 4000 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 8000 kHz, using 4000 kHz
Info : clock speed 4000 kHz
Info : stlink_dap_op_connect(connect)
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Info : STM32F103C8Tx.cpu: Cortex-M3 r2p1 processor detected
Info : STM32F103C8Tx.cpu: target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for STM32F103C8Tx.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Info : device id = 0x20036410
Info : flash size = 64kbytes
Warn : GDB connection 1 on target STM32F103C8Tx.cpu not halted
undefined debug reason 8 - target needs reset
O.K.

O.K.:0xE00FFFD0

Info : dropped 'gdb' connection
shutdown command invoked
```

I tried everything

I changed GDB to OpenOCD

I changed the parameters in `/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.9.0/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.debug.openocd_2.0.200.202202161333/resources/openocd/st_scripts/target/stm32f1x.cfg`
but that didn't work either

My system information

Kubuntu 21.10 x86_64

Kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic

CPU: Intel i7-10700K (16) @ 5.100GHz

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem @Alatriste

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem @Jesse Taube

Comment: @Hatsan125 My colleagues and I decided that our chip was counterfeit and got one from another source and it worked. We did discover that using OpenOCD in the terminal with some params allowed us to use it though.

Comment: And what are those params? For now I have to use Keil IDE.